# Sending commands to adb from android activity

Tags: android, adb, monkey

I find we can start monkey from workstation, by using the following command:

```
adb shell monkey -p <package name> -v 500
```

But when i try to run monkey from emulator's terminal, like this:

```
monkey -p <package name> -v 500
```

it was killed by android, because of insufficient permissions.

I need kick off monkey from the device, (without any connections to PC), my question is, how can i send commands from an android activity to adbd, so I can run monkey from device directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The monkey is implemented in Java, you could integrate it in your app. Or, if you have a rooted device, use `su -c monkey` to run as root. The shell user actually has more permissions than regular app users, that is why you are getting insufficient permissions.

Comment: Thank you Nikolay, another question, i tried download monkey.jar from emulator, since it is in dalvikm format, i can't add monkey.jar in my eclipse build path. do you mean build it from android's source tree?

Comment: Yes, you need to get the source code or a 'regular' jar to build with Eclipse.